# How to redirect to login component in App.js when user not logged in

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-router

If the user is not logged in, I need to redirect the user to Login page
I am using Firebase for login functionality. The code successfully consoles `RRR` but redirect does not work.

But gives following errors:

Error 1)

> TypeError: "this.props.history is undefined"

Error 2)

> InvalidStateError: A mutation operation was attempted on a database
>   that did not allow mutations.

My App.js file looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import firebase from './firebaseConfig';

import Routes from './Routes/Routes';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      user: {}
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.authListener();
  }

  authListener()
  {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        this.setState({ user });
      } else {
        console.log('RRR');
        this.setState({ user: null });
        if(window.location.pathname !== '/') {
            this.props.history.push('/');
        }
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <Routes/>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

My route file is as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Login from '../Components/Login';
import Dashboard from '../Components/Dashboard';

export default class Routes extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
                    <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
                </Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you have to wrap your component in the withRouter function. Then history will be available.  Look at the documentation for examples.

Comment: This could help - https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow